# querying/filtering a list of data inside django template

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, querying

how do i do a filter in a django template? lets say that i have a model like this

```
class Entity:
    attribute1
    attribute2
```

something like that now i have a form.py to submit data into my database

```
Class EntityForm:
    Class Meta:
        model=Entity
```

now in the template i have my form
and in my view i have the contorller of my form

so when everything works fine i get all the data i wanted and now i have so many data that i submited that i want to search for just specific results, now i want to filter/query all the data throught my template, is this posible? how?

i was wondering if i should do something hard because im still learning, i wanted to do a

```
{% entity.objects.filter(atribute2='something') %}
```

but this doesnt work! any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to do that in your template? If the user submitted a search query, that goes to your view first, so that is the appropriate place to do the filter.

As is clearly documented, the template language is expressly restricted, so that you can't call functions with parameters.

Comment: i see, im using the form to submit data to my database, lets say emails, and now in my original template where i put all of the emails i submited i want to do querying/filtering to get specific emails

Comment: That doesn't really do much to explain the situation. How are you doing "querying/filtering" in your template? As I say, each time you perform any kind of action, that's a request, so it goes to your view.

Comment: sorry ill try after this coment to clarify the situation even more, so if i want to filter all the emails with the domain yahoo, i have to do that in my view? even if i want to use a form with attribute2 to filter everything?

Comment: OK, so think about that form: what happens when you click "submit"? Well, obviously, it's going to send a request to the server. And the thing that handles that request is your view. How else would you do it?

Comment: ok i did a search form in my views and now it works, seems to be a bit more complex than i thought, thanks a lot!